# turtle-cli: Error: 'expo-module-prepare' does not exist

Tags: react-native, expo

Trying to build a dev version of an APK (Android) but I keep getting the following error.

```
14572 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 5948ms
14573 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 14ms
14574 timing command:install Completed in 278406ms
14575 verbose stack Error: command failed
14575 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/lib/index.js:63:27)
14575 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
14575 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
14575 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
14576 verbose pkgid @expo/html-elements@0.0.2
14577 verbose cwd /Users/faisaliqbal/.turtle/workingdir/android/sdk42
14578 verbose Darwin 21.3.0
14579 verbose node v16.15.1
14580 verbose npm  v8.11.0
14581 error code 1
14582 error path /Users/faisaliqbal/.turtle/workingdir/android/sdk42/packages/html-elements
14583 error command failed
14584 error command sh -c expo-module prepare
14585 error /Users/faisaliqbal/.turtle/workingdir/android/sdk42/node_modules/commander/index.js:837
14585 error         throw new Error(executableMissing);
14585 error         ^
14585 error
14585 error Error: 'expo-module-prepare' does not exist
14585 error  - if 'prepare' is not meant to be an executable command, remove description parameter from '.command()' and use '.description()' instead
14585 error  - if the default executable name is not suitable, use the executableFile option to supply a custom name
14585 error     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/faisaliqbal/.turtle/workingdir/android/sdk42/node_modules/commander/index.js:837:15)
14585 error     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
14585 error     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
14585 error     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
14585 error     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
14586 verbose exit 1
14587 timing npm Completed in 278532ms
14588 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1656882423113
```

Here are the versions of the app I am using.
Note: This project is working and compiling fine on another machine.

```
OS - darwin 12.2.1 (Monterey)
turtle - 0.27.4
Java (2) Versions:
java 18.0.1.1 2022-04-22
openjdk 11.0.15 2022-04-19
expo - 5.4.12
nodejs - v16.15.1
npm - 8.11.0

setup:android is all good
setup:ios is all good

IPA (IOS Binary) compiles without any issue.
```

```
Command to start the build:
turtle build:android \
  --keystore-path ./keystore/keystore_android.jks \
  --keystore-alias "store (redacted)" \
  --allow-non-https-public-url \
  --gradle-args "--warning-mode all" \
  --public-url expo_url (redacted)  \
  -t apk
```

What might be the causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading NodeJS version from 16 to 14 helped.
I originally installed NodeJS using official installer and after removing the installed version I reinstalled node using brew:

```
brew install node@14
```

(everything else I specified in my question was left untouched.